# Declare structure in header file and implement in source file

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to implement my structure in my product.cpp file, I can't perform an instance of the object, because I get the following error "invalid use of incomplete type".
The temporary solution was to implement my struct in the product.hpp file itself. Is there any way to declare the structure in the product.hpp file and implement it in product.cpp?

My projetc

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "product.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    product* p1 = novo_produto("tangerina", 5, 1.4);

    cout << "Nome produto: " << p1->nome << endl;
    cout << "Preco: " << p1->price << endl;
    cout << "Peso: " << p1->peso << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**product.hpp**

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H
#endif // PRODUCT_H

#include<iostream>
struct product
{
    int price;
    std::string nome;
    float peso;
};

typedef struct product Product;


// metodos

Product* novo_produto(std::string nome, float price, float peso);
```

**product.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "product.hpp"

using namespace std;

Product* novo_produto(string nome, float price, float peso)
{
    Product* p = (Product*)malloc(sizeof(Product));

    p->nome = nome;
    p->price = price;
    p->peso = peso;

    return p;

}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Please extend your [mre] to show how you intend to use the declared but not implemented struct outside of the cpp file which implements it. I think  you are looking for an example of a forward declaration, but you need to clarify.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot reproduce your error. Your header guard is incorrect, but your code appears legal.

Comment: @Beta I think OP has shown the temporary solution and am hence not surprised that it does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think you need to show your build environment. How do you compile&build your project? If you use gcc/makefile/cmake then show us the command or config files.

Comment: @Yunnosch: You're right. I skimmed the question too fast.

Comment: Your `typedef` indicates that you are coming from C. You don't need this in C++. Just call your struct `Product`. Also your code *WILL* fail, because you `malloc` a non-trivial struct. Hence the constructors of its members will not be called.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to declare the structure in `product.hpp` and implement it in `product.cpp`, but it's probably not what you want. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: `(Product*)malloc(sizeof(Product));` is not correct in C++ because it doesn't actually create a `Product`. The C++ equivalent would be `new Product;` instead. But even that should be replaced with `std::make_unique<Product>();` in modern C++ code. But even **that** is probably not needed here. Just using `Product p;` and using value semantics is probably superior in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is plenty of mistakes. Let's start with `product.h` file. First of all, you put a multi inclusion guard. But you need to place your code between `#ifndef` and `#endif` block. Then you need to include string instead of `iostream`. Also, in C++ you do not need to declare typedef to use struct name as a keyword as in the C. So the correct product.h file will be like this.

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H

#include <string>


struct Product
{
    int price;
    std::string nome;
    float peso;
};

// metodos

Product* novo_produto(std::string nome, float price, float peso);

#endif // PRODUCT_H
```

Let's continue with `product.cpp` file. First of all `malloc` is declared in `stdlib.h`, not in `malloc.h`. However, as mentioned in the comments do not use `malloc` in C++. use the `new` operator or smart pointer. Then, your `product.cpp` file will be like that;

```
#include <iostream>
#include "product.h"
#include <memory>
   
using namespace std;
Product* novo_produto(string nome, float price, float peso) {
    
    Product* p = new Product;
    p->nome = nome;
    p->price = price;
    p->peso = peso;
    return p;

}
```

The last file is `main.cpp`. If you use new operator to create an object, then you need to use the `delete` operator to avoid a memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "product.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Product* p1 = novo_produto("tangerina", 5, 1.4);

    cout << "Nome produto: " << p1->nome << endl;
    cout << "Preco: " << p1->price << endl;
    cout << "Peso: " << p1->peso << endl;

    delete p1;

    return 0;
}
```

Then the result will be;

```
Nome produto: tangerina
Preco: 5
Peso: 1.4
```

Also, to get better knowledge please refer [class declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class),  [operator `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), and [operator `delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

Comment: I am very grateful for everyone's collaboration, this answer helped me a lot in many difficulties.